# Rotation about z-axis affects other both axes. Revert axes after rotation in python

Tags: python

I have two lines represented as 3D vectors with their individual start and end points.
The red line is fixed on a base (`R-O`, red vector origin) and can perform a full rotation e.g. between `0°` and `360°` in anticlockwise about `z-axis`.
After a rotation using a given direction vector and angle, its end point `R-E` becomes the new position `R-E'`.

The orange line is connected on its origin point `O-O` with the `R-E` and every rotation applied on the `R-E` rotates it also in the same direction.

Afterwards, it can independently rotate about `y-axis` between e.g. `-90°` and `90°` and becomes the new position then `O-E''`, as shown on the left side.

[image]

If I apply a e.g. `~70°` rotation as shown on `1) Rotation of R-E with O-E on O-O about Z-axis` on the red line `R-E`, the new positions of the red `R-E'` and orange line `O-E'` are fully correct.

But my problem begins after that. The applied additional second rotation on the `O-E'` only about the `y-axis` to become a new `O-E''` brings the orange line in a incorrect direction
each time `(2) Incorrect rotation of O-E’ on O-O’ about Y-axis)`, depending how much I have rotated the red line.

I guess the issue is as follows as shown on the image:
[image]

Since a rotation around `z-axis` affects also the other axes, the second round of the rotation is performed on a wrong axis.
I assume that I have to revert the axes after rotating the red line, so that the applied rotation on the orange line in a desired axes becomes the correct direction as shown on `3) Correct Rotation of O-E’ on O-O’ about Y-axis.`

Thank you for any support.

I implement the functionality as follows:

```
self.red_line_rot_axis = 2 # rotation about z axis
self.orange_line_rot_axis = 1 # rotation about y axis

def visualize_red_line(self):
    self.red_line_origin = [-11.833, -173.2017, 1064.0267]

    self.red_line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
    self.red_line.SetPoint1(origin[0], origin[1], origin[2])
    self.red_line.SetPoint2(self.red_line.GetPoint1()[0], self.red_line.GetPoint1()[1] + 40, self.red_line.GetPoint1()[2])
    self.red_line_origin = self.red_line.GetPoint1()
    self.red_line_curr_pos = self.red_line.GetPoint2()

    self.red_line_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()   
    self.red_line_mapper.SetInputConnection(self.red_line.GetOutputPort())

    self.red_line_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    self.red_line_actor.SetMapper(self.red_line_mapper)
    self.red_line_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    self.red_line_actor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(2)

    self.renderer.AddActor(self.red_line_actor)


def visualize_orange_line(self):
    self.orange_line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
    self.orange_line.SetPoint1(self.red_line_curr_pos)
    self.orange_line.SetPoint2(self.red_line_curr_pos[0], self.red_line_curr_pos[1] + 50, self.red_line_curr_pos[2])

    self.orange_line_origin = self.orange_line.GetPoint1()
    self.orange_line_curr_pos = self.orange_line.GetPoint2()

    self.orange_line_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    self.orange_line_mapper.SetInputConnection(
    self.orange_line.GetOutputPort())

    self.orange_line_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    self.orange_line_actor.SetMapper(self.orange_line_mapper)
    self.orange_line_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.9, 0.6, 0.1)
    self.orange_line_actor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(2)

    self.renderer.AddActor(self.orange_line_actor)

    # Begin with the rotation after representing both lines
    rotate_red_line(self)



# Rotate red and orange line between 0° and x° with 1° increment each time about the origin of red line
def rotate_red_line(self):
    min_angle = 0.0
    max_angle = 50.0  #260 #360
    curr_angle = 1
    for idx in np.arange(min_angle, max_angle, curr_angle):
        rotated_red_line_pos = np.array(rotate_line(self, self.red_line_rot_axis,  self.red_line_origin , self.red_line_curr_pos, curr_angle))
        rotated_orange_line_pos = np.array(rotate_line(self, self.red_line_rot_axis,  self.red_line_origin , self.orange_line_curr_pos, curr_angle))

    # Visualize the rotation
    update_red_line_pos(self, rotated_red_line_pos, rotated_orange_line_pos)

    if curr_angle == max_angle:
        # Rotate the orange line afterwards
        rotate_orange_line(self, rotated_red_line_pos, rotated_orange_line_pos)

    curr_angle = np.round(curr_angle + 1, 2)

# Update the positions of the lines after rotation
def update_red_line_pos(self, rotated_red_line_pos, rotated_orange_line_pos,):

    self.red_line.SetPoint2(rotated_red_line_pos)

    self.orange_line.SetPoint1(rotated_red_line_pos)
    self.orange_line.SetPoint2(rotated_orange_line_pos)

 # Rotate orange line between -20° and x° with 1° increment each time about the origin of 
 orange line
 # The origin of the orange line is the new position of the red line
 def rotate_orange_line(self, rotated_red_line_pos, rotated_orange_line_pos):
    min_angle = -20.0
    max_angle = 180.0
    curr_angle = 1
    for idx in np.arange(min_angle, max_angle, curr_angle):
        rotated_orange_line_pos = np.array(rotate_line(self, self.orange_line_rot_axis,  rotated_red_line_pos , rotated_orange_line_pos, curr_angle))

        # Visualize the rotation
        update_orange_line_pos(self, rotated_orange_line_pos)

        curr_angle = np.round(curr_angle + 1, 2)

# Update the position of the orange line after rotation
def update_orange_line_pos(self, rotated_orange_line_pos):

self.orange_line.SetPoint2(rotated_orange_line_pos)


# 3D rotation matrix
def rotate_line(self, axis_direction, origin, point_to_rotate, angle):

    angle = np.radians(angle)
    a, b, c = origin
    x, y, z = point_to_rotate


    if axis_direction == 0:
        u, v, w = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0] # Rotate about x axis
    elif axis_direction == 1:
        u, v, w = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]  # Rotate about y axis
    elif axis_direction == 2:
        u, v, w = [-0.1027, -0.1525, 0.9829] # Rotate about z axis

    cos = np.cos(angle)
    sin = np.sin(angle)
    qx = (a*(v**2 + w**2) -u*(b*v + c*w - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + x*cos + (-c*v + b*w - w*y + v*z) * sin
    qy = (b*(u**2 + w**2) -v*(a*u + c*w - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + y*cos + (c*u - a*w + w*x - u*z) * sin
    qz = (c*(u**2 + v**2) -w*(a*u + b*v - u*x - v*y - w*z)) * (1-cos) + z*cos + (-b*u + a*v - v*x + u*y) * sin

    return qx, qy, qz
```

Comment: Sounds like gimbal lock. Try using a quaternion.

Comment: I don't think so. Because it goes sometimes to the correct direction `y-axis` but with some offset. Therefore non of the three axes are locked.